# Open FileDialog using VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I download reports on a daily/weekly basis but when downloading the system auto generates the file name with a date at the end although the basic file name is the same. ie ANAPOS - 20141001. I'm using a simple open command (Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\903270\Documents\Excel\ANAPOS.txt") to do some other stuff but before doing so I need to rename the file to ANAPOS.txt before I can run it.
Is there any code that will allow my macro to search for ANAPOS with out all the other info at the end?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: get a file list from the folder you mention (filter down to "ANAPOS*") and open the ANAPOS file which has the date you want in the name. Here's a simple file list solution: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/getting_a_list_of_file_names_using_vba/

Answer (score 0):

Set `filePath` to where you want to search

```
Sub getANAPOS()
Dim Filter As String, filePath As String

filePath = "C:\Data\VBA\SO\"
Filter = "ANAPOS files (*.txt), filepath & ANAPOS*.txt"

ANAPOSSelectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter)

End Sub
```

**EDIT FOLLOWING CLARIFICATION BY OP**

Sticking with the same theme, this should give you some scope to work with. It essentially 'automatically' renames the selected file in situ, unless it already exists.  Acknowledgements to @Gary's Student for his neat ideas to parse the GetOpenFileName result, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038711/vba-get-file-name-from-path-and-store-it-to-a-cell).

```
Sub renameANAPOS()
Dim Filter As String, filePath As String, newName As String

'filter txt file names containing 'ANAPOS'
Filter = "ANAPOS files (*.txt), filepath & ANAPOS*.txt"

'the 'rename' name
newfName = "ANAPOS"

'navigate to original ANAPOS file and location details
ANAPOSSelectedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter)

'parse selected file details
fullArr = Split(ANAPOSSelectedFile, "\")
detArr = Split(fullArr(UBound(fullArr)), ".")
fullArr(UBound(fullArr)) = ""
fPath = Join(fullArr, "\")
fName = detArr(0)
fExt = detArr(1)

'rename file in not already exixts
    If Len(Dir(fPath & newfName & "." & fExt)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox newfName & "." & fExt & " already exists in this folder."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Name ANAPOSSelectedFile As fPath & newfName & "." & fExt
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks barryleajo, but not quite what I was after, my explanation may not have been that good in the first place (Sorry, new at this), What I need to do is rename the original file from ANAPOS-xxxx.txt (Where xxxx is a variable and changes every time I download the file) to ANAPOS.txt.