# Grab filenames from directory and put into cells

Tags: vba, excel

I need to grab all the filenames of a particular filetype in a folder, and put each filename into a separate cell, preferably going down by rows. I also need to make sure that there aren't any duplicate filenames and that this will work for any folder, as it's supposed to be dynamic.

Basically, I need to do something similar to this, but looped and I need to put in a check to make sure it's not already in the workbook: 
[VBA Get File Name From Path and Store it to a Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038711/vba-get-file-name-from-path-and-store-it-to-a-cell)

I've tried using Application.GetOpenFilename, Dir() function, and some other stuff here:

[count files in specific folder and display the number into 1 cel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753701/count-files-in-specific-folder-and-display-the-number-into-1-cel)

[Using Excel VBA to loop through .csv files in folder and copy the filename into cells in last column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40712094/using-excel-vba-to-loop-through-csv-files-in-folder-and-copy-the-filename-into)

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

the code I had is pretty barebones (new to programming) before I used other's code:

```
Sub Add_Policies()

'let user select folder, go into folder, grab all filenames which end in .htm, put each into a separate cell, one after the other.
'This needs to be dynamic, so probably put in an Update List button. Msgbox "x number of policies were added. There are now a total of y policies."
'check if policy is already present. if so, skip.
'add functionality to open a policy in excel



Dim fldr As FileDialog, nFiles As Integer, fldrName As String, FileDifference As Integer, FileName As String


    'Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\Hothi\Documents"
        If .Show = -1 Then 'if ok is pressed
            fldrName = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With


If fldrName <> "" Then

    With fldrName
    path = fldrName & "\*.htm"

    FileName = Dir("path")

    Do While FileName <> ""
        nFiles = nFiles + 1
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop



    For i = 1 To nFiles
        Range("A3").Offset(i, 0) = nFiles
        Range.Value = Dir(



    Next

    If nFiles <> nFiles Then
        msgbox (" & FileDifference & number of policies added. There are now a total of & nFiles & policies.")
        Else: msgbox ("No new policies, check location of new policies.")
    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: So you've tried things ...and? Do you have some code you're trying to use? Can you post the relevant code, and any errors or unexpected behavior, to this post instead? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well we know you can copy links anyway... that's not really how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

The code to do this will look like this.

```
Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\"

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

    r = 14
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" &amp; FileItem.Path &amp; """,""" &amp; "Click Here to Open" &amp; """)"

        r = r + 1   ' next row number
    Next FileItem

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub GetFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, Subfolders As Boolean)

'--- For Example:Folder Name= "D:\Folder Name\" and Flag as Yes or No

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, SubFolder As Scripting.folder
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
'Dim r As Long
    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    '--- This is for displaying, whereever you want can be configured

    r = 14
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(r, 2).Formula = r - 13
        Cells(r, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(r, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
        Cells(r, 5).Formula = FileItem.Size
        Cells(r, 6).Formula = FileItem.Type
        Cells(r, 7).Formula = FileItem.DateLastModified
        Cells(r, 8).Formula = "=HYPERLINK(""" &amp; FileItem.Path &amp; """,""" &amp; "Click Here to Open" &amp; """)"

        r = r + 1   ' next row number
    Next FileItem

    '--- This is the Function to go each and Every Folder and get the Files. This is a Nested-Function Calling.

    If Subfolders = True Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If

    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Got to the link below, scroll down to the button named 'Download Now' and click that to download a copy of a utility that will do all the work for you, just as you described.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Comment: This works, just needed to reference "is to reference the Microsoft Scripting dll into your project" as per @David Eisenbeisz answer, adding that to this would make it perfect answer.
I also changed the &amp; to just & - probably a HTML / text problem...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to reference the Microsoft Scripting dll into your project and use a scriptobject to get the directory.  Then you would need to parse through the directory entries to get the files you want and put them in cells.  I don't recall the specific commands to get the files as a scriptobject, but I am sure it is fairly well represented in various posts on this site and others.  I didn't come up with the idea by myself, but I've done exactly what you are asking.  I just don't remember which workbook it needed it for or I would post an example.

Another option is to open up a command prompt and break out good ol' DOS to feed a DIR command into a textfile that you can then use excel VBA to parse.  I'm showing my age here, but I don't know enough about what you are really trying to do to know if this is a viable option or not.